# Visual boardgame

Tags: c#, unity3d

The visual board game is currently a game in unity, where I've created a map and a grid. The visualization is like this:
[image]

Making this code obviously needed nested for loops and the like, but developing this I mainly had the attitude "just go with it", which means I now have rather confusing code.

I have created a class which currently contains all my code, and I believe I need to do some cleanup on my variables, and maybe move some methods to other classes?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class gridInit : MonoBehaviour {

    static int mapWidth = 33;
    static int mapHeight = -27;
    static float tileSizeUnits = 0.333333333333333333333f; this float is cancer, I'm sorry
    public GameObject tile;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GenerateObjects();
        GenerateTileMap();
        Screen.fullScreen = true;  

    }

    void Awake()
    {

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    bool walkable = false;
    private void GenerateTileMap()
    {
        int tileNumber = 0;
        for (float y = 0; y > mapHeight; y--)
        {
            for (float x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
            {
                tile.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
                GameObject go = Instantiate(tile, new Vector3(x/3, y/3, -2), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                tileNumber++;
                go.name = "tile" + tileNumber;
                go.tag = "grid";

                RaycastHit2D hit;
                Vector3 fwd = go.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
                Debug.DrawRay(go.transform.position, fwd * 50, Color.green);
                hit = Physics2D.Raycast(go.transform.position, fwd, 200);
                if (hit)
                {
                    go.tag = "walkableGrid";
                    Debug.Log("works");
                }         
            }
        }
    }

    public GameObject center;
    public GameObject stair;
    public GameObject corner;
    public GameObject straight;
    public GameObject empty;
    public GameObject stair90;
    public GameObject stair180;
    public GameObject stair270;
    public GameObject corner90;
    public GameObject corner180;
    public GameObject corner270;
    public GameObject straight90;
    public GameObject mainCenter;

    private void GenerateObjects()
    { 
        GameObject[,] map = new GameObject[9, 11] { { empty, center, corner180, stair180, stair180, stair180, stair180, stair180, corner270, center, empty }, { center, center, straight, center, stair270, stair180, stair90, center, straight, center, center }, { straight, corner270, center, corner180, center, center, center, corner270, center, corner180, straight }, { corner, center, straight, center, center, stair180, center, center, straight, center, corner90 }, { stair270, center, center, center, stair270, mainCenter, stair90, center, center, center, stair90 }, { corner270, center, straight, center, center, stair, center, center, straight, center, corner180 }, { straight, corner, center, corner90, center, center, center, corner, center, corner90, straight }, { center, center, straight, center, stair270, stair, stair90, center, straight, center, center }, { empty, center, corner90, stair, stair, stair, stair, stair, corner, center, empty } };
        int tileNumber = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) 
            {
                GameObject go = Instantiate(map[i,j], new Vector3(j + tileSizeUnits, (i * -1) - tileSizeUnits, 0), map[i,j].transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                tileNumber++;
                go.name = "object" + tileNumber;
                go.tag = "path";
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a mandatory rule but camelCase for classes is little bit weird in C#. `gridInit` should be `GridInit`. Also you may want to pick a better name for that. *Init* is clear but it doesn't help to understand what will be initialized (and then responsibilities of this class). Class isn't inherited then it should be `sealed` too.

Consistency. Sometimes you use private to denote `private` methods and sometimes you don't (because it's default). One way or the other but do not mix otherwise reader will have to understand if he is missing something...

With `static int mapWidth = 33`; you declare a read/write public fields. Few things here. You should not have public writeable fields. Public fields should be PascalCase. You do not need `static` but `const`. This is true for all of them.

Isn't easier to declare `tileSizeUnits` as `const float TileSizeUnits = 1.0f / 3;`?

When you want to *expose* object outside your class you should use read-only properties: `public GameObject Tile { get; private set; }`. I strongly doubt you need all those public objects (aren't they just implementation details? Is this a mere factory class?) but I don't see all surrounding code then I'm just guessing. What I think is worse is that you're *holding* a lot of objects and this class just handles some initialization code. Not enough to do for a class and too much for a single method. I think if you merge it into calling code you will have easier to read code...

`GenerateTileMap()` has some magic numbers. Make constants from them and reader won't need to understand (guess) what they are.

In `GenerateObjects()` I don't see the need for `map` object. 2D array isn't the easiest thing to read (especially when initialized in this way, at least don't make it single-line). A single `for` (with integer division and modulus to calculate row/column where required) is much easier to read (IMO). The problem (I think) is that here you're receiving a bunch of objects but that logic is somewhere else.

Comment: Great review, highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

@Adriano Repetti has listed so many issues that I have only one short comment...

> ```
> GameObject[,]
> ```

If you don't have to, you shouldn't use multidimensional arrays. Linq cannot work with them. It's better to use jagged arrays `GameObject[][]`